# uninstall lubuntu 13.04 to not interfere with built in win 7 installer

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, 13.04

Due to software problems, I need to uninstall lubuntu 13.04 off of my computer. It is a vaio and has a built in function to install windows 7 from scratch without a disk, I usually use this when I need to reinstall windows so it works pretty well.

About two years ago I had lubuntu installed and had to switch back to windows. When I used the restore function It gave me an error along the lines of "failed to save grub" (I dont remember the exact text). Apparently this had to do with lubuntu not being removed properly. luckily i had a win 7 recovery disk lying around and used command prompt to fix the problem.

Unfortunately I no longer have a recovery disk, is there a way to properly uninstall lubuntu so that the built in windows install can properly work?

Comment: Is windows listed in the grub menu? If not there is no "built in windows install". The laptop may have come with windows, but you have removed it. Without a recovery CD you cannot install windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a place where you can download a copy of windows 7 legitimately. What I did was go to the piratebay.se and download myself a copy and of windows 7. I do not condone pirating but by doing this you can burn the CD and have access to the recovery utilities. I personal do not consider this pirating because I am not using the software other than just the recovery tools, and I have paid for windows so I just re install with the computers product key if i have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed download Windows 7 iso legally from digitalriver, Microsoft's online distribution parter.   Pick your language: [forums.mydigitallife.info](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/28517-Windows-7-w-o-SP1-and-SP1-Media-Refresh-Direct-Download-Links)

You can remove the `ei.cfg` from the install iso to enable different editions selection.  You can also inject the oem certificate and oem key by following step 6 of the "Official Windows 7 Repository" thread on mdl forums.  But using the key from the sticker on the computer is easier.